# Why is my Word Press site looking for images from my last website address

Tags: wordpress, web-testing

so I recently was having trouble installing a Word Press premium theme, I spoke to support, they told me to tell them the IP of the site. Since it was ran on my XAMPP server I had to change the address from "http://localhost/mywordpresssite" to "http://123.123.123.123/mywordpresssite" (my IP) in wordpress settings. I then port forwarded, then sent that IP off and everything worked, they fixed the issue and all is well.

So then I changed the IP back to "http://localhost/mywordpresssite". (what it was originally). The Website started to run extremely slow after changing it back, I then realise it's due to the website looking for several images that are hosted on my IP "http://123.123.123.123/" and since the address doesn't work on my computer, (even when the website was working perfectly for the support team), the website ran extremely slow, due to only loading when time out errors occur.
My Website Console whenever I try to access the website at the moment....

http://123.xxx.xxx.xxx/mywordpresssite/wp-content/uploads/revslider/slide_min_1.jpg  
http://123.xxx.xxx.xxx/mywordpresssite/wp-content/uploads/revslider/slide_min_2.jpg  
invalid height tween value: NaN
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

There is nothing in my website that says the IP that it's trying to find those images from. I even installed Velvet Blues Update URLs to ensure that the IP had been changed. I've cleared Cache and tried on 3 different browsers. (Chrome, IE and Firefox). Still no luck.

If anyone has any idea on what's happening, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install some application in local is:

- Create a [virtualhost](https://impress.org/how-to-setup-xampp-wordpress-virtual-hosts/)
- Restart apache
- In your database, replace all occurrences of old url with new local url (for example: http://www.local-wordpress.com)

In your case, moreover, seems that it's a problem with Revolution Slider (maybe it's integrated into your theme): check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179645/revolution-slider-invalid-left-tween-value-nan)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is answering my problem. Please help.